# Having trouble understanding Java Overflow and Compile error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, overflow

I am a Java newbie and studying int overflow!
While playing with some integers I was surprised with some weird results

```
    int x = 2147483647 + 1;    
    x == > - 2147483648 

    int x = 2147483647 + 2;
    x ==> -2147483647
    
    int x = 2147483647 + 2147483647;
    x ==> -2

    int x = 2147483647 + 2147483648; 
    **compile error**
```

I thought integer overflow would not cause any compile error. Also, it is hard for me to understand how outputs for the overflow are calculated (ex. why int x = 2147483647 + 1 // x ==> -2147483648)
Can anybody please expalin the logic of these results?

Thanks!!

Comment: `2147483648` simply can't be assigned to an int literal because it's too big. You can never have an int-valued expression with that value.

Comment: if you are getting a compilation error , please mention it, because in this case it itself explains what you are looking for, it will also help other people who are reading the question

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Comment: I appreciate for your feedback! I am still learning how things work in this website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (2^31).
>
> All decimal literals from 0 to 2147483647 may appear anywhere an int literal may appear. The decimal literal 2147483648 may appear only as the operand of the unary minus operator - (§15.15.4).
>
> It is a compile-time error if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator; or if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2^31).

You can't use 2147483648 as an `int` literal because an `int` literal is an `int` expression, and thus must have an `int` value; but 2147483648 is too large to be used as an `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

You can get IntegerOverflow while computing values together as your first 3 examples

The problem here about `2147483648` is kind of the same but difference, as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647` you cannot store more in an `int` that's why you get an compilation error  `2147483648` is too big to fit in. Even before runtime you already can't fit the value in an `int`, which is different of the overflow that occurs at runtime

Answer (score 2):

> Also, it is hard for me to understand how outputs for the overflow are
>   calculated (ex. why int x = 2147483647 + 1 // x ==> -2147483648)

Whenever you the overflow or underflow happens, the value starts from the other end e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);// Will be equal to Integer.MIN_VALUE
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1);// Will be equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483648
2147483647
```